# Piggyback off blackberry's internet connection via bluetooth to an iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch

I've got a blackberry and an ipod touch. I can connect to the net at anytime with the BB using the cellular network. However, the touch requires a wi-fi connection.

I know its possible to share the BB's data connection with a pc. I'm curious if its possible to do with an iPod touch?

Answer (score 1):

actually there is. First you need to download PDAnet for blackberry. ON the BB you need to setup up your APN according to the carrier. AND MAKE SURE TO DISABLE "DIAL UP NETWORKING" ON THE BLUE TOOTH SETTINGS.

THEN, you need to jailbreak your ipod touch, go into cydia and download an app call iBluever. (try the free version first). Google you setting for ibluever according to your carrier. And Voila. youshould be able to tether your blackberry to your ipod touch via bluetooth. I do this all the time with my curve 9300 and my iphone 3g

Answer (score 0):

Theres no official way nor a jailbroken way. its a shame really because it would make an alternative to the expensive iphone. there are a few "in development" jailbroken apps but still nothing official